# show-paren-mode or similar to highlight multi-character parentheses

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

In latex, "parentheses" such as `\(\)`, `$$` and `\[\]` are constantly used. Is there a way to customize `show-paren-mode` or is there some other mode to highlight these multi-character parentheses in `latex-mode` as well as the traditional ones, `()[]{}`?

Taking this to the next level, is there a way to highlight beginning and end of latex environments? As in the example below (`item` is just an example)

```
\begin{item}  % <- should be hightlighted together when point is inside
OTHER TEXT
\end{item}    % <- should be hightlighted together
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found about the [Simple Minded Indentation Engine](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html) in Emacs which uses show-paren to highlight multi-character parenthesis like `\(` `\)` (See `smie-closer-alist`).